# using webshot inside a docker container

Tags: r, docker, phantomjs

I try to use `webshot` (and [phantomjs](/questions/tagged/phantomjs)) inside a [docker](/questions/tagged/docker) container

please have a look to this minimal `Dockerfile`

```
FROM rocker/geospatial

RUN R -e 'webshot::install_phantomjs()'

RUN apt-get update -qq && apt-get install -qy \
    ca-certificates \
    bzip2 \
    curl \
    libfontconfig \
    --no-install-recommends \
    && curl -SL https://bitbucket.org/ariya/phantomjs/downloads/phantomjs-2.1.1-linux-x86_64.tar.bz2 > phantom.tar.bz2 \
    && bzip2 -d ./phantom.tar.bz2 \
    && tar -xvf ./phantom.tar -C /usr/local/ --strip-components=1 \
    && rm phantom.tar \
    && apt-get -qy remove bzip2 curl \
&& rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*
```

then

```
docker build . -t test
docker run -it test bash
```

and inside `R`

```
webshot:::find_phantom() #"/usr/local/bin/phantomjs"
system("ping www.r-project.org") # ok
webshot::webshot("https://www.r-project.org/", "r.png") # nothing happend
```

Any idea why?

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is probably because by default, you are at the root of the distribution and you can not write on it.

If I try this:

```
~$ docker run -it rocker/geospatial bash
~$ R

> webshot::install_phantomjs()
> webshot:::find_phantom()
```

[1] "/root/bin/phantomjs"

```
> list.files() # At the root /
> setwd("/home/rstudio/kitematic/") # Go to allowed directory
> webshot::webshot("https://www.r-project.org/", "r.png")
> list.files()
```

[1] "r.png"